# How to manage environment variables in one settings file for dev and prod in Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to merge local and prod settings files to one.

**local.py**

```
...
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['DJANGO_SECRET_KEY']
DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG']
```

**prod.py**

```
...
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
```

As I don't use AWS env variables in local, I want the compiler not to check those env variables and also, is there a way to check if the environment is dev or prod so that I can do something like the below?

**settings.py**

```
if env == local:
  DEBUG = True
else:
  DEBUG = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', <default>)` - this way Python won't throw KeyError but I still feel that you should keep seperate local and production settings, and just point locally to the local version.

This also answers the second question, because in local.py you can set

```
DEBUG = True
```

and you won't have the need for

```
if env == local:
  DEBUG = True
else:
  DEBUG = False
```

Also, you can set up base.py settings, which would have settings that would repeat in prod.py and local.py. If you want you can take a look at https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django - it sets up the project structure that is recommended in the book Two Scoops of Django.